# Adding a custom option to the Catalog Product view in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm new to Magento development, yet proficient in PHP. I've been banging my head about this for the last couple of days, and i'm just lost in XML files.

I'd like to add a custom category to the product catalog menu, and add a custom view to it, to create a management page for some specific parameters for the product.

[image]

Up until now i've followed many tutorials, most of them outdated or didnt really explain why i was doing what i was doing. I found most documentation out of date and/or incomplete, namely the [wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/All%20Categories?idx=5_-_modules_and_development).

Am i missing some really obvious documentation, or holy grail of getting started guide? I've got a basic plugin running, can anyone explain to me how to add a category in the catalog view?

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: So i'm going to try to post it to their forums. However, Chrome wouldnt log me in, it only seems to work with Firefox. Now i cant find the damn "New topic" button. (edit: found it! Too bad it takes a page 17 seconds to load.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Magento lacks in documentation. Here are some good resources for finding what you want to do:

- http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Magento-Extension-Developers-Guide-v1.0.pdf

  - Look at pp. 44 for developing in the admin panel

#### Additional Resources

- http://alanstorm.com/category/magento
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/resources/magento-user-guide

Sorry it's not the exact solution you're looking for but I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! I did read much of the first document, and was excited to read an instruction for an example extension. 30 pages later i kinda gave up, as i was just copy pasting stuff, not knowing what i was doing.
However i'll continue reading the admin section.

Comment: In the end i did manage to hack something in together, thanks for the links!